# MSSQL aggregate (count) one column but show string based on different column from last matching row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table such as below. The `code` never changes for each type of item, but the `description` may have been entered inconsistently. There is no way to go back and fix old data due to regulatory requirements in our industry, but we have fixed our input form so users cannot enter incorrect descriptions moving forward. In other words, the most recent descriptions are the correct descriptions that should be used.

I want to count how many times each `code` appears, but I want it to be shown as the most recent `description`.

| id | code | description | other stuff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09G | jacket | blah blah |
| 2 | 270 | pants | blah blah |
| 3 | 13B | t-shirt | blah blah |
| 4 | 09G | coat | blah blah |
| 5 | 09G | sweater | blah blah |
| 6 | 13B | shirt | blah blah |

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT
  TOP 10 code, count(*)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  code
ORDER BY
  count(*) DESC
```

Which gives me:

| code | value |
| --- | --- |
| 09G | 3 |
| 13B | 2 |
| 270 | 1 |

This is correct, but instead of the code, I would like it to show the most recently entered description - such as:

| code | value |
| --- | --- |
| sweater | 3 |
| shirt | 2 |
| pants | 1 |

The following code will get me close, but it returns the string that is "last" in alphabetical order, not necessarily the last *entered* (aka, the matching description with the largest `id`):

```
SELECT
  MAX(description) as description, count(*)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  code
ORDER BY
  count(*) DESC
```

Comment: It's in my question: "aka, the matching description with the largest id"

Comment: how do you distinguish the "most recent" entry for given code? do you have a date column you can rely on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "most recent" means "highest `id`":

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT description, 
         value = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY code), 
         rn    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY id DESC)
  FROM dbo.[table]
)
SELECT description, value
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY value DESC;
```

Results:

| description | value |
| --- | --- |
| sweater | 3 |
| shirt | 2 |
| pants | 1 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=730137805b2b7959e71d255b69ea6027)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This works exactly as I hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using 2 subqueries joined together, but I like the common table expression approach better.

```sql
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
    [id]          INT         NOT NULL,
    [code]        CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
    [description] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Data
(
    [id],
    [code],
    [description]
)
VALUES
(1, '09G', 'jacket'),
(2, '270', 'pants'),
(3, '13B', 't-shirt'),
(4, '09G', 'coat'),
(5, '09G', 'sweater'),
(6, '13B', 'shirt');


SELECT [descriptions].[description], [counts].[count]
FROM
       (
           SELECT   [code], COUNT(*) AS [count]
           FROM     @Data AS [d]
           GROUP BY [code]
       ) AS [counts]
       INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT [ordered].[code], [ordered].[description]
           FROM
                  (
                      SELECT [code],
                             [description],
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [code]
                                                ORDER BY [id] DESC
                                               ) AS [rn]
                      FROM   @Data
                  ) AS [ordered]
           WHERE  [ordered].[rn] = 1

       ) AS [descriptions]
           ON [descriptions].[code] = [counts].[code];
```